# Are there any tools to warn possible misusage of delete or delete []?

Tags: c++, vector, delete-operator, scalar

I think I am clear on the difference between delete and delete []. The question I am asking here is: sometimes I do have typo and use the wrong one. Then it may or may not crash and normally ends up with hours of debugging.

I wish gcc can detect and give warning on possible misusage on a few simplest cases.
I still have to use "new float[size]" from time to time because of legacy functions that I need to call, so I am more interested in find an error checking tool to catch part of these mistakes.

Comment: You don't need to use `new float[size]`.  Use `std:array<float>` or `std::vector<float>`.

Comment: One tool: don't use `new[]`. There's `vector` for that (in almost any case).

Comment: use valgrind on the executable

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `new` either. Use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Comment: Thanks for all the valuable suggestions. Valgrind is too slow for me (the program might run hours to reach the problematic code in optimized mode, then valgrind with debugging mode put this to days ... typically 100 times slower -- not 10 time slower!) I will avoid new[] as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I wish gcc can detect and give warning on possible misuage on a few simplest cases.*

Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

> *I still have to use `new float[size]` from time to time because of legacy functions that I need to call*

No, you don't. If a legacy function wants a pointer to the first element of an array of floats, do this:

```
std::vector<float> numbers(10);
legacy_func(&numbers[0]);
```

Don't do this:

```
float *numbers = new float[10];
legacy_func(numbers);
delete[] numbers;
```

Comment: If you have a modern compiler use `numbers.data()` instead.

Comment: I liked numbers.data(). After 1-2 years, I had to change them back to &numbers[0]. Sometimes they want the code to be built with old compilers ...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to put your floats in a `std::vector<float>` and then pass `front()` or `&front()` to those legacy functions.  I'm not sure this is guaranteed to work by the standard, but it ought to work in common implementations.

If you have C++11 library support and `size` is known at compile time, `std::array<float, size>` will be more efficient.

Comment: When the size is known at compile time, `new` isn't an option, anyway.